# magento add layout xml to add javascript not working

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to add a system.xml to add custom javascript to magento on every page. It is not working, and so far as i see my layout xml is not being added.

This is my code:

app/code/local/mynamespace/mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <mynamespace_mymodule>
            <version>1.0.0.1</version>
        </mynamepace_mymodule>
    </modules>
        <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mynamespace_mymodule.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/mynamespace_mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>mynamespace/mymodule/js/myscript.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This is not working. I am quite stuck at how to debug this. I added logging in \Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::getFileLayoutUpdatesXml() to see all $updateFiles[]. I do not see mynamespace_mymodule.xml in there, so i assume i added my layout xml in a wrong way.

I copied the relevant code from there to here, just to show how i am trying to see which files are added:

```
$updatesRoot = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode($area.'/layout/updates');
foreach ($updatesRoot->children() as $updateNode) {
    if ($updateNode->file) {
        Mage::log((string)$updateNode->file);
        ...
    }
}
```

This is code from mage/core, i just added the log. It logs when i refresh the layout cache.

Answer (score 0):

Is your module being loaded at all?

do you have a module xml file to enable the extension / module?

app/etc/modules/mynamespace_mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<mynamespace_mymodule>
    <active>true</active>
    <codepool>local</codepool>
</mynamespace_mymodule>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding js and css files like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <css src="Namespace_Module::css/styles.css"/>
    <script src="Namespace_Module::js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Namespace_Module::js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Class" name="Namespace_Module" template="Template.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Then on your module web folder (view/frontend/web), create js and css folders and place your files there.